# How to check if something is true for a user defined (EditText) amount of time?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile

I'm attempting to implement a function in Android (Java) that has a user enter a `int` in an 
`EditText` and use that **Specific** `int`'s value in seconds to determine if that a statement is true for that many seconds and return a result, otherwise, restart the check to see if the condition has been true for user-defined amount of seconds.

I've been attempting something like this

```
//Under MainActivity
public double userDefined = Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString()); //Returns Null Pointer Error?

//Function in MainActivity
private Runnable Condition = new Runnable() {
        private boolean killed = false;
        boolean flag = true;

        public void run() {
            while (!killed) {
                try {
                    if (valueA < valueB) {
                        while (flag) {
                            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep((long) userDefined);
                            if ((valueB < valueA)) {
                                /* Do stuff */
                                flag = false;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                   catch(InterruptedException ex){
                        killed = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
// Not sure if done here need to return stuff done...
```

Answer (score 0):

The null pointer exception is because the layout is not yet inflated.

solve:

All components should be used/initialized after 
 setContextView(R.Layout....)
in oncreate() method.